# Assembly Language: Memory Bytes and Offsets

Tags: memory, assembly, byte, offset

I am confused as to how memory is stored when declaring variables in assembly language. I have this block of sample code:

```
val1  db  1,2
val2  dw  1,2
val3  db  '12'
```

From my study guide, it says that the total number of bytes required in memory to store the data declared by these three data definitions is 8 bytes (in decimal). How do I go about calculating this?

It also says that the offset into the data segment of **val3** is 6 bytes and the hex byte at offset 5 is 00. I'm lost as to how to calculate these bytes and offsets.

Also, reading **val1** into memory will produce 0102 but reading **val3** into memory produces 3132. Are apostrophes represented by the 3 or where does it come from? How would **val2** be read into memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two bytes, `0x01` and `0x02`. That's two bytes so far.

Then you have two *words,* `0x0001` and `0x0002`. That's another four bytes, making six to date.

The you have two more bytes making up the characters of the *string* '12', which are `0x31` and `0x32` in ASCII <sup>(a)</sup>. That's another two bytes bringing the grand total to eight.

In little-endian format (which is what you're looking at here based on the memory values your question states), they're stored as:

```
offset  value
------  -----
     0   0x01
     1   0x02
     2   0x01
     3   0x00
     4   0x02
     5   0x00
     6   0x31
     7   0x32
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The character set you're using in this case is the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) one (you can follow that link for a table describing all the characters in that set).

The *byte* values `0x30` thru `0x39` are the digits `0` thru `9`, just as the bytes `0x41` thru `0x5A` represent the upper-case alpha characters. The pseudo-op:

```
db '12'
```

is saying to insert the bytes for the characters `'1'` and `'2'`.

Similarly:

```
db 'Pax is a really cool guy',0
```

would give you the hex-dump representation:

```
addr  +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F  +0123456789ABCDEF
0000  50 61 78 20 69 73 20 61 20 72 65 61 6C 6C 79 20   Pax is a really 
0010  63 6F 6F 6C 20 67 75 79 00                        cool guy.
```

Comment: +1 for the table. but the byte at offset 1 should be 2 I believe.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for the helpful table! So words are always read into memory backwards? And can you help explain why '12' is represented as 0x31 and 0x32?

Comment: @raphnguyen there are two methods for representing words. this backwards order is called big endian and the other is called little endian. '12' is a string. 0x31 and 0x32 are the ASCII codes for '1' and '2'.

Comment: @raphnguyen: see the update, hopefully that explains it better.

Answer (score 3):

`val1` is two consecutive bytes, `1` and `2`. `db` means "direct byte". `val2` is two consecutive words, i.e. 4 bytes, again 1 and 2. in memory they will be `1, 0, 2, 0`, assuming you're on a big endian machine. `val3` is a two bytes string. `31` and `32` in are 49 and 50 in hexadecimal notation, they are ASCII codes for the characters "1" and "2".

Comment: I've always heard it pronounced as as "data byte".